# I'm writing a method using spring-boot that calls a.py file, and when I request this method, the code for py doesn't run

Tags: java, spring-boot

I call the.py file in a basic java project and it takes about 30 seconds to run.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process proc;
        String line ="";
        BufferedReader in;
        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\anaconda\\python.exe " +
                    "D:/2017/Python/pythonProject8/main.py " +
                    "D:\\2017\\Python\\pythonProject8\\flower1.jpg");
            proc.waitFor();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg8wS.jpg)
But this code is skipped when I use spring-boot.

```java
@GetMapping("test")
    public String test(){
        System.out.println(1);
        Process proc;
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\anaconda\\python.exe " +
                    "D:/2017/Python/pythonProject8/main.py " +
                    "D:\\2017\\Python\\pythonProject8\\flower3.jpg");// 执行py文件
            proc.waitFor();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                result += line;
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(2);
        return result;
    }
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PqZ9.jpg)

I want to know how to run spring-boot properly.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your.py file takes a long time to run then you shouldn't use Process and use ProcessBuilder instead.

```java
public ArrayList<String> getPasswords(String path) throws IOException {
        String result = "";
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\anaconda\\python.exe ", "D:\\2017\\Python\\pythonProject8\\main.py",path);
  //The path here is me.py needs to be passed in
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        final Process process = processBuilder.start();
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String s = null;
        int i = 0;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null)//This if is I need to ignore some of the output
        {
            i++;
            if (i >6) {
                result += s + '\n';
            }
        }
        if (!result.equals("")){
            return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(result.split("\n")));
        }
        return new ArrayList<String>();

    }
```

You may run an error "DLL load failed while importing XXXX".
Please update the packages required for python.